# overflow on parent div prevent box-shadow to display

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>` with a soft `box-shadow` and I want to wrap it inside a `<div>` so that I can make the content overflow on x-axis (the real table is large, I need this effect in smaller screen).

It's straightforward but when I add the CSS property `overflow-x: auto;` on the wrapper `<div>` the `box-shadow` is not yet displayed correctly (only the right side box-shadow is visible, and only in larger screen).
Please refer to [this JSbin example](http://jsbin.com/ruhirovaze/1/edit?html,css,output) where the first table is the correct visualization while the second one has the glitch.

How can I solve the problem without removing the overflow property?

Comment: So if you add overflow, it will hide shadow of child. Move shadow to parent.

Comment: Why are you using `overflow` here?

Comment: @Justinas given the `width: 100%` on parent it doesn't work when it's too large

@PraveenKumar on a small display I want the table to scroll left-right. Try to reduce the browser window width to see the effect

Comment: @Naigel Than add padding on parent same size as shadow

Comment: @Justinas nice idea! I can add `padding: 5px; margin: -5px;` to the parent `<div>`! Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add padding for parent same size as shadow.

Comment: small addition, to remove the added padding, add negative margin with the same padding value.
ex - padding: 1rem; margin: -1rem